# What are the advantages of using 'required' for required HTML fields

Tags: ruby-on-rails, forms, input, required

We have a web application built on ruby on rails.
When we have required `input` fields in forms we redisplay the form if they are blank.
The logic and messaging is handled by the rails framework so that the form page gets redisplayed with the appropriate error markup indicating required field(s).
This does not actually require that the required `input` fields have the `required` attribute as detailed at http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_input_required.asp
Are there valid reasons to suggest adding the `required` attribute to forms that already seems to work?

Answer (score 2):

Not sure if I really got your question, however, `required` attribute is client side validation and rails redisplay the form with messages after server side validation.

Both types of validations are recommended. Client side validation saves server hits, whereas, client side HTML/JS can be updated/removed and tweaked by user therfore, server side validation makes sure that everything is valid in reality.

Hope it helps

Comment: Yes helpful. plus 1.  The ability to avoid an actual server trip and avoid using client side js is a big plus!

Comment: Glad to know that it helped

Answer (score 0):

As @RAJ already said, it saves server hits and makes therefore your application faster. "Normal" users are able to submit the form only if it's values are valid. He gets an error response immediately and the browser never submits it to the server.

But I would highly recommend you to combine your client-side validation with Javascript to write custom error messages or you will get probably different error messages in different browsers.

And of course - never forget to make server-side validation :).